# Magento 2 add multiple products to quote

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem

I want to add multiple products to quote, but its adding only 1st product. I have used `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory` for creating quote.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $this->product->loadByAttribute('sku', $item['sku']);
    if (!is_object($product)) {
        //If product not avilable then display error message
        echo(__(' Material with code ' . $item['sku'] . ' does not exist!' . '<br/>'));
        continue;
    }
    $product = $this->product->load($product->getId());
    $productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($product->getId());
    if (!$productStock->getIsInStock()) {
        //If product out of stock then display error message
        echo(__(' Material with code ' . $item['sku'] . ' is out of stock!' . '<br/>'));
        continue;
    }
    //check for porduct quantity
    if ($productStock->getQty() < $item['confirmedQuantity']) {
        echo(__(' Material code ' . $item['sku'] . ' does not have ordered quantity!' . '<br/>'));
        continue;
    }
    $product->setPrice($item['grossPrice']);
    $quote->addProduct($product, null);
    $quote->setCreatedAt($this->getDate($item['purchaseOrderDate']));
    echo $item['sku'] . "==";
}
//check quote item count
echo count($quote->getAllVisibleItems());
```

Quote count always print 1; there are 5 products in item array; output for `item['sku']`:

```
24-MB01==24-MB02==24-MB03==24-MB04==24-MB05==
```

but its always adding 1st product to quote. I have also checked in database.

Comment: accept the answer If you find it helpful so it helps other community members :)

Answer (score 3):

It create an issue because,you have used this in your `constructor`

```
protected $_product;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $_product 
    ) {
        $this->_product = $product;        
    }
```

***Instead of this use below code constructor injection***

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_product 
    ) {
        $this->_product = $product;        
    }
```

And replace

```
$product = $this->product->load($product->getId());
```

with this

```
$product = $this->_product->create()->load($product->getId())
```